# How long is a time loop in The Forgotten City

Tags: the-forgotten-city

The Forgotten City is self-described as a game about time loops, there's a mystery afoot and you need to take advantage of the ability to reset time to solve it. While you can trigger a reset on demand (accidentally or otherwise) if you just bumble around long enough eventually a telegraphed event takes place that will inevitably force a reset

> The election

After this happened the first time it made me paranoid on all subsequent loops about taking too much time doing stuff such that "the event" would take place while I was in the middle of something or in an inconvenient place which would make the act of resetting the time loop difficult/impossible

> Returning to the Shrine of Proserpina

So I'm curious, what is the trigger for "the event" that eventually forces the restart? Is it time based (it happens after x minutes), event based (whenever this happens "the event" triggers), some mix of both (it happens after x minutes but will not happen offscreen) or something else entirely?